# Valid flag get decline, what should I do?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I've just flagged an unclear question and my flag get decline. For the the moment it's fine.

But, hour later, the question get suspend for the exact same flag that I give. What am I suppose to do with this? Is it normal? Does it happens really often?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986526/reading-data-from-a-file-and-assign-them-to-variables) using a custom moderator flag that said:

> This "question" contains no question.

By using a custom flag you are requiring a moderator to review the flag and act on it.  The problem is a moderator didn't need to be involved, so the flag was declined.

Moderators should be flagged for things that the community cannot handle themselves.  In the future, you should use the standard close flags to send questions into the close vote review queue.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, thanks. I would used the standard close flags but I don't have the permission yet.

Comment: @AnthonyLiard You gain the [privilege to flag posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) at a rep of 15. You had enough rep to flag, you just used the wrong flag.  You'll use a flag to close > then select the appropriate flag.

Comment: Sorry, but I need 50 reputations for certain flags
http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: @AnthonyLiard It's still not something that a moderator should be involved in. Moderators should be involved in things that the community cannot handle themselves.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on SO and I'm learning by my mistakes. It would not happen again. Thank you  for your help.

Comment: @AnthonyLiard Don't worry about a declined flag, we all get them.  :)

Comment: @AnthonyLiard The fact that you don't have enough reputation to do the action you want to do doesn't make it acceptable to do some other inappropriate action.  In the same way that posting a comment as an answer isn't okay just because you don't have enough rep to comment.  You simply need to wait until you *do* have enough rep.

Answer (score 3):

Had you flagged the question for closure as "unclear" the flag couldn't possibly have been declined.  It could have been disputed, but never declined.  Flags for closure don't go to mods, and only mods can decline flags.

You used some other type of flag reason than flagging the question for closure, possibly a custom mod flag.  Custom moderator flags should only be used when it is beyond the community's ability to handle the situation, which is not the case when a question is unclear and should be closed.

Since you used the wrong type of flag reason, the flag was declined, even though the post did merit some moderation.

Comment: Do you have any example of situation that can't be handle by the community that would need the use of custom flag?

Comment: @AnthonyLiard A user constantly making inappropriate edits to posts, or rolling back appropriate edits.  A mod is needed to deal with a rollback war.  That said, mod flags should generally be *very* rare.  Almost all problems that come up can be solved by the community in some way without moderator involvement.

Comment: @AnthonyLiard If you suspect suspicious voting, if you see a user repeatedly posting the same link over and over, migrating a post to a site not in the standard list. There are many things that a moderator would need to step in to do, but closing questions isn't one of them.